# drupal website locahost subdirectories pages 404 error

Tags: php, apache, drupal, virtualhost, bitnami

I have created a virtual host for a drupal website on Windows 10 using Bitnami (WAMPstack),
and when start the website , i can access to the home page only but not to sub pages or sub-directories.

in the windows etc folder i did update the hosts file and added

```
127.0.0.1       website.local
```

also edited the httpd.conf enabled the virtual host

```
(Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)
```

also edited the httpd-vhosts file : added the follwoing

```
<Directory C:/vhosts>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.15-0/apache2/htdocs/website/"
  ServerName website.local
</VirtualHost>
```

when i start browsing the site and click on any subpage i got a 404 (Not Found)
please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing some directives on the directory level. Here is a config that works that basically follows https://www.drupal.org/node/953296#comment-9866119

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/myrepo/mydocroot
    ServerName mysite.localhost

    <Directory /home/myrepo/mydocroot >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to activate the mod_rewrite in apache.

Edit the httpd.conf and search for "#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" remove the "#". Save and restart the apache.